# Reaproveitar o Navigation Drawer em outras Activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Criei uma Activity Navigation Drawer, configurei os menus, personalizei para minha aplicação. E agora? Como eu faço para criar novas activitys reutilizando Navigation Drawer criando para a primeira?